# How do I activate cron job?

Tags: macos, cron

I edited the cron file on my Mac running catalina.

I used this code:

```
crontab -e
```

And then I added this line

```
* * * * * python3 ~/Documents/Scripts/script.py
```

My expectation is that it should run every minute but it hasn't run once.

Do i need to do something special to activate cron on this machine?

Updated my code based on the conversation in the comments to this

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 ~/Documents/Scripts/script.py >>~/Documents/Scripts/script.log 2>&1
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to activate it, you have to *troubleshoot* it. One obvious problem is that cron jobs run with a very minimal environment, and `python3` probably isn't in its `PATH`. There may be other environment dependencies. To help discover them, capture its output (especially error output) by adding something like `>>~/Documents/Scripts/script.log 2>&1` to the job entry. Also, see [the serverfault question on cron troubleshooting](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it).

Comment: It said that it couldn't open the file with `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted`. I'm wondering if this is a chmod problem

Comment: It's basically the same problem as this thread except in that thread they didn't reach a solution https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379718/cant-run-python-script-from-automator-on-catalina-operation-not-permitted

Comment: I ran chmod -R 777  ~/Documents/Scripts/ and I'm getting the same error

Comment: Try changing your tildes (~) into `$HOME`

Comment: I replaced the tilde with the full path name and I get the same error

Comment: It's probably failing because of the personal information protection restriction Apple added in Mojave. Private data, like the contents of ~/Documents, aren't accessible except from apps that you've granted access to... and your cron job isn't even an app. See [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys). Can you move the script (& associated files) to a "public" location?

Comment: That fixed it, mind putting that as the answer so I can accept it?